# wmic DiskDrive where (MediaType!='Removable media') get model return unexpected values when SetLocal EnableDelayedExtensions are set

Tags: cmd, wmic

for example, this code

```
wmic DiskDrive where (MediaType!='Removable media') get model
```

return all storage devices in system except removables

but this code

```
SetLocal EnableelaysedExtensions
wmic DiskDrive where (MediaType!='Removable media') get model
```

return quite the opposite - only removable devices in system.

Is there some way to fix it?
I need SetLocal directive in script for other purposes, so I can not remove it.

Comment: `SetLocal EnableelaysedExtensions` surely gives you a syntax error and has no influence on the exclamation mark because it certainly doesn't enable [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: `wmic DiskDrive where (MediaType^^!='Removable media') get model`

Answer (score 0):

The command line `SetLocal EnableelaysedExtensions` results in the error message:

> Invalid parameter to SETLOCAL command

The command **SETLOCAL** supports four different parameters as it can be read by running `setlocal /?` in an opened [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window:

- ENABLEEXTENSIONS / DISABLEEXTENSIONS
- ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION / DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

I suppose the wanted code is something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ModelCount=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DiskDrive where (MediaType^^!^="Removable media"^) GET Model /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    set /A ModelCount+=1
    set "Model!ModelCount!=%%I"
)
set Model
pause
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** runs in this case in background with Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DiskDrive where (MediaType!="Removable media") GET Model /VALUE 2>nul
```

The output of **WMIC** being Unicode encoded with UTF-16 Little Endian (LE) with Byte Order Mark (BOM) is processed by **FOR**.

The exclamation mark `!` must be escaped in this case with two `^` because of enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to be interpreted as literal character and not as beginning of a delayed expanded environment variable reference. The command line is parsed twice by the Windows command processor because of enabled delayed expansion. For that reason on first parsing `^^!` becomes just `^!` and on second parsing the caret character is now interpreted as escape character for the explanation mark and for that reason just `!` is passed to `cmd.exe` started in background respectively `wmic.exe` executed in background.

The equal sign `=` in `where` clause must be also escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character as otherwise `cmd.exe` processing the batch file would interpret it as argument separator and replace the equal sign by a normal space character which would make the `where` clause invalid.

The `)` must be also escaped with just one `^` to be interpreted as literal character and not as end of the set for command **FOR**. The two round brackets of `where` clause are not really necessary. So it would be also possible to use:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DiskDrive where MediaType^^!^="Removable media" GET Model /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
```

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `wmic` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Please note that a disk drive model string assigned to loop variable `I` containing one or more exclamation marks would be assigned wrong to the environment variable because of the second parsing of the command line `set "Model!ModelCount!=%%I"` due to enabled delayed expansion results in interpreting the exclamation marks in string assigned to loop variable `I` as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

Please note further that a disk drive model string with an equal sign in the string would be also not correct processed because of using the **FOR /F** options `tokens=2 delims==`. But I have never seen a disk drive with an `=` in its model name. That should be never a problem.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic diskdrive /?`
- `wmic diskdrive get /?`

See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for your command should be:

```ruby
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "MediaType != 'Removable media'" Get Model
```

However, when delayed expansion is enabled the `!` character has a special meaning, and is in this case disregarded.

The simplest fix for that is to use an alternative to the `!=` operator. If you take a look at the available [WQL operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-operators), you should note that you can instead use, `<>`:

```ruby
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "MediaType <> 'Removable media'" Get Model
```